# SQL Server : incorrect syntax near '=' Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: c#, sql-server

The following is the query in my C# Windows application. The query deletes an item from the database:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete Articulos set CODIGOPRODUCTO = '" + 
    textBox1codigo.Text + "', CODALTER = '" + textBox1codAlterno.Text + 
    "', DESCRIPCION = '" + richTextBox1descripcion.Text + 
    "', PRECIOVENTA = '" + textBox1precioVenta.Text + "', COSTO='" + 
    textBox1costo.Text + "', IVAPORCENTAJE='" + textBox1iva.Text + 
    "', IDPROVEEDOR = (SELECT IdClienteProveedor FROM ClienteProveedor WHERE " + 
    "RAZONSOCIAL = '" + comboBox1proveedor.Text + "') WHERE IdArticulo='" + IDARTICULO + 
    "'", Login.VENTAS);
```

but executing it throws the following errors:

> Error: SQL incorrect syntax near '='
>
> Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Comment: Check how stackoverflow highlighted your query.

Comment: Don't compose query string, use parameters.

Comment: Why do you use SET and actually trying to update row values within delete query? Shouldn't it be just Delete from Articulos WHERE IdArticulo='" + IDARTICULO + "'"

Answer (score 2):

are you trying to update a record? 
if yes change the `delete` to `update`
Else if you want to delete a record remove the `set` part just put

```
Delete From YourDatabase Where <This>=<this>.
```

and take note that `single quote` is used to declare string in sql not `double qoute` you must escape single quotes instead of double quotes.